# How to convert a float to a Parquet TIMESTAMP Logical Type?

Tags: python, parquet, pyarrow

Let say I have a pyarrow table with a column `Timestamp` containing `float64`.
These floats are actually timestamps experessed in s.
For instance:

```
import pyarrow as pa
my_table = pa.table({'timestamp': pa.array([1600419000.477,1600419001.027])})
```

I read about Parquet Logical Type from [documentation](https://github.com/apache/parquet-format/blob/master/LogicalTypes.md).
Please, how can I convert these float values to the Logical Type [TIMESTAMP](https://github.com/apache/parquet-format/blob/master/LogicalTypes.md#timestamp)?
I see no documentation about the way to do this.

Thank you for your help.
Have a good day,
Bests,

Comment: I think your best option is to first convert the floats into an actual `timestamp` type in pyarrow, and then it will automatically by written to a paruet logical timestamp type.

Comment: Hi @joris, thanks for trying to help. Please, do you have any pointer to help me figure how to do that firsthand? Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to convert the floats into an actual timestamp type in pyarrow, and then it will automatically be written to a paruet logical timestamp type.

Using the `pyarrow.compute` module, this conversion can also be done in pyarrow (a bit less ergonomic as doing the conversion in pandas, but avoiding a conversion to pandas and back):

```py
>>> import pyarrow.compute as pc
>>> arr = pa.array([1600419000.477,1600419001.027])
>>> pc.multiply(arr, pa.scalar(1000.)).cast("int64").cast(pa.timestamp('ms'))
<pyarrow.lib.TimestampArray object at 0x7fe5ec3df588>
[
  2020-09-18 08:50:00.477,
  2020-09-18 08:50:01.027
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'll be able to convert within arrow from floats to timestamp.

Arrow assumes timestamp are 64 bit integers of a given precision (ms, us, ns). In your case you have to multiply your seconds floats by the precision you want (1000 for ms), then convert to int64 and cast into timestamp.

Here's an example using pandas:

```
(
    pa.array([1600419000.477,1600419001.027])
    .to_pandas()
    .mul(1000)
    .astype('long')
    .pipe(pa.Array.from_pandas)
    .cast(pa.timestamp('ms'))
)
```

Which gives you:

```
<pyarrow.lib.TimestampArray object at 0x7fb5025b6a08>
[
  2020-09-18 08:50:00.477,
  2020-09-18 08:50:01.027
]
```